# Get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error when compiling aspectJ project

Tags: compilation, maven, aspectj

I get

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

when I try to compile an aspecj project. The project is a maven 2 project and I have set maven-compiler-plugin to use up to 2048m memory. But this error just doesn't go away. What else can I do to increase the heap space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try tips specified [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg55073.html), including

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=Xmx1024M
```

Comment: Actually I put this: set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m

Comment: exactly, -D sets system properties, not vm args